# How to intiate an HTTP request in a new python process

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

A child process is crashed every time when it makes an http request.

I need to make an HTTP call from a child process in python. When I spawn a new process with a method that makes an HTTP call using requests module, the newly spawned process crashes. In the below code, simple_method works fine in a new process but call_api() crashes it. What's wrong here?

```py
import multiprocessing
import requests

def call_api():
    print(requests.get('https://api.github.com'))

def simple_process():
    print('Hi')

multiprocessing.Process(target=simple_process).start()
multiprocessing.Process(target=call_api).start()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "crashes it"? Can you add the error message?

Comment: Both functions crash on my machine (Windows 10, Python 3.7). You have to start the processes inside a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block.

Comment: It runs fine as-is on Ubuntu, Python3.5. You need to specify the error message, your OS, your Python version, and how you are running this block of code.